# How to make navigation bar background color to clearColor?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

My profile view controller is embedded inside the Navigation controller and it shows up with coloured navigation bar. But I want to avoid that or how to make navigation bar background color to clearColor. So that it can show the images below it eg. Twitter app

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
[self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                         forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very sample,
You can try:

```
YourNavigation.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

YourNavigation: Enter your NavigationController.

If this can help, you can mark for me!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    [self.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                     forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
```

in swift

```
   self.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
   self.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
   self.navigationBar.translucent = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in AppDelegate's `didFinsihLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; // This is for clear navigation bar 
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage new]]; // this for remvove line under the navigationbar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new]
                                              forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't make navigation bar as clear . Just add you custom view then make it clear.